# Code Explanation of IP Checksum function by Mixter (C & Linux)

Tags: c, raw-sockets

I was reading the famous networking tutorial on raw UDP sockets by Mixter, and while reading source code I became confused with this function:

```
     unsigned short     /* this function generates header checksums */
     csum (unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
     {
              unsigned long sum;
              for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
              sum += *buf++;
              sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
              sum += (sum >> 16);
              return ~sum;
     }
```

The function has an empty character array passed to it:

```
    char datagram[4096];
```

Which is supposed to "contain the ip header, tcp header, and payload." It also has an integer passed to it which is "nwords". The function is called like this:

```
    iph->ip_sum = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->ip_len >> 1);
```

Where "iph->ip_len" would be the total length of the ip header. What I am confused about is the reason why datagram is casted to "(unsigned short *)" and what effect this would have on a character array. Also, I know how a checksum algorithm works, but I am confused about the actual code, and why each step is done. Can someone please explain the casting as well as what each line in the function does?

This is the tutorial: http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~steflik/cs455/rawip.txt

Comment: I got the feeling the above code only works for big-endian hardware. (or: little endian would give different results) The buffer also needs to be padded (by the caller) with NUL characters to an even boundary.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am confused about is the reason why datagram is casted to `(unsigned short *)`

It's casted to `unsigned short *` because that's the type what `csum()` expects.

> and what effect this would have on a character array

It would be treated as a (pointer to the first element of an) array of `unsigned short`s instead of an array of `char`s, which makes the code invoke undefined behavior, since it's now accessing an object through an incompatible pointer type, violating the strict aliasing rule.

Apart from that, when this `csum()` function <s>works</s> appears to be working, it most probably reads `unsigned short`s, composed of two elements of the original `char` array.

Comment: OP: So then what would be the appropriate call?